# 2 HDs in RAID 1 with 2 partitions?

Tags: partition, raid1, windows-xp

i am not very familiar with raid partitons and am not even sure if this is the right place to ask about it, but i hope that if it is not that some one can point me on the right direction.

This is my situation, i have 2 500 GB hds and a 3ware pci-e hardware for raid and i wanted to make a RAID 1 but i dont know if i can make more then one partition for it, for instance:

MAIN HD:
os partition: 100GB
data partition: rest of left size

and make the RAID 1 either work on all the HD or just on the data partition of it.

that is on windows xp sp3 and the 3ware allows bootable raid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have a 3ware card, the RAID itself can be done at the hardware level. This needs to be done before you install windows on the system, through the BIOS of the RAID card itself (read the docs if you're unsure about how to get there, I think it's alt-3 during boot up)

Once you've created a RAID 1 on the two disks, your OS installs will only see a single 500 GB disk. You are then free to partition this as you like.

If you haven't already set up the RAID on the two disks, and you have already installed windows, I think your only resolution is to backup your data and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks a lot i was not aware of this. That was totally the information i was looking for. I havent installed anything yet but i have had the HD's used on a linux server but they are clear, by that i meant they have no partitions any more nor any data i need to rescue or save at all ...

So all i need is to plug my card in and alt-3 during boot to set it up then install windows as i wish ? thanks :)

Comment: Look on 3Ware's website for docs for that card if you don't have the docs. Really you shouldn't look here for in-depth instructions; we can only give pointers and hints since if we don't have the card, we are just guessing from experience.

Comment: You *might* need drivers for the card when you go to install Windows. You should be prepared for that ahead of time if you don't have the installation docs and CD already (or floppy, I don't know what version of the OS you're setting up.)

Comment: windows xp like i said on the main topic, thanks a lot that was enough to get what i was confused about. I have the cd with drivers and inside the cd the is also the docs etc... i will take a look at it as soon as i get released to go home :), once again thanks for the head start with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the RAID1 array will look like any disk to the system - so you can partition it any way you like.